# Passing application controller method to mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass a method from the application controller to a mailer to send shopping cart contents to email.

Method in the application_controller.rb:

```
def current_order
    if session[:order_id].present?
        Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
        Order.new
    end
end
```

Mailer:

```
class CartMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "from@example.com"

    def send_cart_contents
        @order = current_order
        mail(to: "to@example.com", subject: 'Order from the site')
    end
end
```

And the view:

```
Order from the site
<% @order.order_items.each do |oi| %>
    <%= oi.product.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting an error: undefined local variable or method 'current_order'.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

UPDATE

If I'm passing it as a parameter:

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/cart_mailer
class CartMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    def cart_mailer_preview
        CartMailer.send_cart_contents(current_order)
    end
end
```

I'm also getting NameError.

UPDATE 2

CartMailerPreview don't have access to the current_order, so to test it just pass an id with the parameter. When you use it normally all works well.

Comment: Where is your send_cart_contents being called from ?

Comment: Now I'm calling it from the cart_mailer_preview.rb (ActionMailer::Preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CartMailer` is not going to have visibility to the `current_order` defined in `application_controller.rb`. This is a good thing.

Best practices is to have the `send_cart_contents` method accept the order so that it can mail it out:

```
class CartMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "from@example.com"

    def send_cart_contents(order)
        @order = order
        mail(to: "to@example.com", subject: 'Order from the site')
    end
end
```

This way you can mail out a cart from a background job and isolates your mailers from your controllers. Relying on a global `current_order` is not a good practice.

Comment: Anyway I don't get how can I access my order if it stored in a session?

Comment: @AntonKhaybulaev when using `CartMailerPreview` you'll need to do: `CartMailer.send_cart_contents(Order.find(<some_id>))`

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out. When I use it normally (not from CartMailerPreview) it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass current_order to the mailer as a parameter.

Comment: Okay I get it, but if I'm passing it as a parameter, I'm also getting NameError. I'll update initial post.